# Prisma Error with Supabase: must be owner of event trigger pgsodium_trg_mask_update

Tags: postgresql, psql, prisma, supabase, pgsodium-trg-mask-update

I've been using Prisma with a PostgreSQL database hosted on Supabase and encountered a perplexing issue. When I try to execute `npx prisma db push`, I get this pesky error message:

```bash
Error: db error: ERROR: must be owner of event trigger pgsodium_trg_mask_update
```

I get a warning about possible data loss, but even after confirming to ignore it, I end up with the above error. The warning details are as follows:

```bash
⚠️  There might be data loss when applying the changes:
  • You are about to drop the column `xyz` on the `Example` table, which still contains n non-null values.
  • ... [other warnings] ...
```

I've already validated my schema with npx prisma validate, and everything looks good there.

Has anyone else run into this issue, or does anyone know how to solve it?

Answer (score 0):

I finally cracked this tough nut! If you're dealing with this error while using Prisma, PostgreSQL, and Supabase, you may need to drop and recreate some extensions directly in your Supabase SQL query interface (or via CLI):

Execute these commands:

```sql
drop view vault.decrypted_secrets;
drop extension supabase_vault;
drop extension pgsodium;
create extension pgsodium;
create extension supabase_vault;
```

It seems like there was an extension conflict or some sort of ownership issue with the event triggers. Running these commands sorted everything out for me.